# Windows adds a 'slash' at the end of Run dialog input

Tags: windows, windows-8, skype

In Windows 8 you can call someone over Skype by using a simple command in the Run dialog:

```
skype://username
```

This will run the Skype and start calling the given username automatically.

Here funny things happen. Windows 8 seems to add a "/" by itself at the end of the Run dialog input string. It ends up looking like this:

```
skype://username/
```

This makes the call fail because Skype is trying to reach a username with that "/" at the end (slashes are not even allowed in Skype usernames!).

Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: The obvious answer is to open skype and call them that way, although not too helpful :)

Comment: We're making a small "kiosk" out of Windows 8 computer. The idea is to allow users to call our Skype hotline with a single click. We have created a Metro tile that executes any Run dialog input and it works - but the dreaded slash prevents it from actually calling anyone successfully.

Comment: I would try making a .bat file, to see if win 8 adds the slash through that means, I would assume/hope not.  you could have the bat ask for the username or a pre-defined list :)

Comment: If you wrote the app, modify it to strip off any trailing slash?

Comment: @MarkAllen - OP did not write the app. They are using **`builtin`** feature executed from the **`Run`** dialog box.

Comment: @KevinFegan I must have misunderstood what he meant by "We have created a Metro tile". Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `skype:username` instead of `skype://username`.

Since both of them start with `skype:`, windows sends them both to Skype and skype knows how to take out the first two slashes.

However, it looks like Windows automatically adds the trailing slash to anything that it identifies as a bare website domain.  Since Skype URLs look like regular website domains, Windows adds the trailing slash.

---

Note also, that Windows 8 Store urls also will only work without the slashes, using `ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=...`

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `skype /callto:username`

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA171/can-i-run-skype-for-windows-desktop-from-the-command-line